# how to pass email address from checkout form to charge page with Stripe

Tags: php, forms, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's custom checkout button and I can create charges successfully. What I want to do now is pass the e-mail address on the form and create a new customer. However, the email address doesn't get passed to my server rather it goes directly to Stripe.

**I was hoping I could do something like this:**

```
//pass value from input field on previous page
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Create a Customer
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  "card" => $token,
  "description" => "$email")
);
```

**But I don't want to ask the user for his email address twice, since Stripe's form already asks for it.**

**How can I capture the email address to create a new customer?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok then...while I didn't know the rules here, here's the answer:

Using the Stripe checkout.js

In your `token` callback, you can access `res.email` the same way you access `res.id` which will give you the email that the user submitted. Here's the code:

```
  var token = function(res){
      var $theToken = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
      var $theEmail = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeEmail />').val(res.email);
      $('form').append($theToken);
      $('form').append($theEmail).submit();
  };
```

You could also put them in an array and then use a

```
$.each(
```

But that would be as an exercise for you to use.  Cheers, -Colin

Comment: Note: In the above you can actually add/append anything as a pass through, that you want to receive from the client side to the server side. Take for instance any user data or program or app data you need.

Answer (score 10):

The email is posted along with the token.

It's passed into a post variable: $_POST['stripeEmail'].

Comment: Is this *always* passed, or does Stripe sometimes not prompt the user for their email?

Comment: @mightyspaj, it's not always passed but going on the original question states, if you don't pass it then the user will get asked for their email address again.

Comment: @beech sorry that wasn't really clear. So because the user will be prompted for their email if you don't pass it, doesn't this mean the email will *always* be there?

Comment: @mightyspaj I'm not sure, but I'm going to take a guess at yes.

Comment: this will work if you are using a standard checkout script. However it won't work if you are creating a custom handler (to handle variable amount), MediaBlinkk's solution will work in that custom case.